# Pytorch: Variable data has to be a tensor, but got Variable

Tags: python, variables, pytorch, apollo, tensor

i am stuck and confused... I am using the same code at 2 places one is my personal computer using Pycharm and other on my university provided server (GPU is bigger). And code is working fine and training data and producing result on my computer which has (8 gigs of GPU) while the same code is not working on the server (i am using "apollo") and giving the following error:

```
yeosiz@apollo:~/YAN/color$ python3 main.py
<IPython.core.display.Image object>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 133, in <module>
    model = ColorizationNet()
  File "main.py", line 55, in __init__
    resnet.conv1.weight = nn.Parameter(resnet.conv1.weight.sum(dim=1).unsqueeze(1))
  File "/data/yeosiz/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/nn/parameter.py", line 25, in __new__
    return super(Parameter, cls).__new__(cls, data, requires_grad=requires_grad)
RuntimeError: Variable data has to be a tensor, but got Variable
```

Error block of code 1:

```
class ColorizationNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size=128):
    super(ColorizationNet, self).__init__()
    MIDLEVEL_FEATURE_SIZE = 128

    ## First half: ResNet
    resnet = models.resnet18(num_classes=365)
    # Change first conv layer to accept single-channel (grayscale) input
    resnet.conv1.weight = nn.Parameter(resnet.conv1.weight.sum(dim=1).unsqueeze(1))
    # Extract midlevel features from ResNet-gray
    self.midlevel_resnet = nn.Sequential(*list(resnet.children())[0:6])

    ## Second half: Upsampling
    self.upsample = nn.Sequential(
      nn.Conv2d(MIDLEVEL_FEATURE_SIZE, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
      nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2),
      nn.Conv2d(128, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
      nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
      nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2),
      nn.Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
      nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Conv2d(32, 2, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
      nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2)
    )

  def forward(self, input):

    # Pass input through ResNet-gray to extract features
    midlevel_features = self.midlevel_resnet(input)

    # Upsample to get colors
    output = self.upsample(midlevel_features)
    return output
```

and

```
model = ColorizationNet()
```

I tried to use `out.data.numpy()` but did not work !!

This is the code:

```
  # Move data into training and validation directories
import os

import matplotlib
from IPython.display import Image, display

# For plotting
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#%matplotlib inline

# For conversion
from skimage.color import lab2rgb, rgb2lab, rgb2gray
from skimage import io

# For everything
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F

# For our model
import torchvision.models as models
from torchvision import datasets, transforms
# For utilities

import os, shutil, time

os.makedirs('images/train/class/', exist_ok=True)  # 40,000 images
os.makedirs('images/val/class/', exist_ok=True)  # 1,000 images
for i, file in enumerate(os.listdir('testSet_resize')):
    if i < 1000:  # first 1000 will be val
        os.rename('testSet_resize/' + file, 'images/val/class/' + file)
    else:  # others will be val
        os.rename('testSet_resize/' + file, 'images/train/class/' + file)

        # Make sure the images are there

display(Image(filename='images/val/class/0b4803802caabfdc98dfe1ba22298848.jpg'))

# Check if GPU is available
use_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()





class ColorizationNet(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, input_size=128):
    super(ColorizationNet, self).__init__()
    MIDLEVEL_FEATURE_SIZE = 128

    ## First half: ResNet
    resnet = models.resnet18(num_classes=365)
    # Change first conv layer to accept single-channel (grayscale) input
    resnet.conv1.weight = nn.Parameter(resnet.conv1.weight.sum(dim=1).unsqueeze(1))
    # Extract midlevel features from ResNet-gray
    self.midlevel_resnet = nn.Sequential(*list(resnet.children())[0:6])

    ## Second half: Upsampling
    self.upsample = nn.Sequential(
      nn.Conv2d(MIDLEVEL_FEATURE_SIZE, 128, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
      nn.BatchNorm2d(128),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2),
      nn.Conv2d(128, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
      nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Conv2d(64, 64, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
      nn.BatchNorm2d(64),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2),
      nn.Conv2d(64, 32, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
      nn.BatchNorm2d(32),
      nn.ReLU(),
      nn.Conv2d(32, 2, kernel_size=3, stride=1, padding=1),
      nn.Upsample(scale_factor=2)
    )

  def forward(self, input):

    # Pass input through ResNet-gray to extract features
    midlevel_features = self.midlevel_resnet(input)

    # Upsample to get colors
    output = self.upsample(midlevel_features)
    return output
class GrayscaleImageFolder(datasets.ImageFolder):
  '''Custom images folder, which converts images to grayscale before loading'''
  def __getitem__(self, index):
    path, target = self.imgs[index]
    img = self.loader(path)
    if self.transform is not None:
      img_original = self.transform(img)
      img_original = np.asarray(img_original)
      img_lab = rgb2lab(img_original)
      img_lab = (img_lab + 128) / 255
      img_ab = img_lab[:, :, 1:3]
      img_ab = torch.from_numpy(img_ab.transpose((2, 0, 1))).float()
      img_original = rgb2gray(img_original)
      img_original = torch.from_numpy(img_original).unsqueeze(0).float()
    if self.target_transform is not None:
      target = self.target_transform(target)
    return img_original, img_ab, target

class AverageMeter(object):
  '''A handy class from the PyTorch ImageNet tutorial'''
  def __init__(self):
    self.reset()
  def reset(self):
    self.val, self.avg, self.sum, self.count = 0, 0, 0, 0
  def update(self, val, n=1):
    self.val = val
    self.sum += val * n
    self.count += n
    self.avg = self.sum / self.count

def to_rgb(grayscale_input, ab_input, save_path=None, save_name=None):
  '''Show/save rgb image from grayscale and ab channels
     Input save_path in the form {'grayscale': '/path/', 'colorized': '/path/'}'''
  plt.clf() # clear matplotlib
  color_image = torch.cat((grayscale_input, ab_input), 0).numpy() # combine channels
  color_image = color_image.transpose((1, 2, 0))  # rescale for matplotlib
  color_image[:, :, 0:1] = color_image[:, :, 0:1] * 100
  color_image[:, :, 1:3] = color_image[:, :, 1:3] * 255 - 128
  color_image = lab2rgb(color_image.astype(np.float64))
  grayscale_input = grayscale_input.squeeze().numpy()
  if save_path is not None and save_name is not None:
    plt.imsave(arr=grayscale_input, fname='{}{}'.format(save_path['grayscale'], save_name), cmap='gray')
    plt.imsave(arr=color_image, fname='{}{}'.format(save_path['colorized'], save_name))



model = ColorizationNet()
criterion = nn.MSELoss()
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-2, weight_decay=0.0)

# Training
train_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.RandomResizedCrop(224), transforms.RandomHorizontalFlip()])
train_imagefolder = GrayscaleImageFolder('images/train', train_transforms)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train_imagefolder, batch_size=64, shuffle=True)

# Validation
val_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(256), transforms.CenterCrop(224)])
val_imagefolder = GrayscaleImageFolder('images/val' , val_transforms)
val_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(val_imagefolder, batch_size=64, shuffle=False)

def validate(val_loader, model, criterion, save_images, epoch):
  model.eval()

  # Prepare value counters and timers
  batch_time, data_time, losses = AverageMeter(), AverageMeter(), AverageMeter()

  end = time.time()
  already_saved_images = False
  for i, (input_gray, input_ab, target) in enumerate(val_loader):
    data_time.update(time.time() - end)

    # Use GPU
    if use_gpu: input_gray, input_ab, target = input_gray.cuda(), input_ab.cuda(), target.cuda()

    # Run model and record loss
    output_ab = model(input_gray) # throw away class predictions
    loss = criterion(output_ab, input_ab)
    losses.update(loss.item(), input_gray.size(0))

    # Save images to file
    if save_images and not already_saved_images:
      already_saved_images = True
      for j in range(min(len(output_ab), 10)): # save at most 5 images
        save_path = {'grayscale': 'outputs/gray/', 'colorized': 'outputs/color/'}
        save_name = 'img-{}-epoch-{}.jpg'.format(i * val_loader.batch_size + j, epoch)
        to_rgb(input_gray[j].cpu(), ab_input=output_ab[j].detach().cpu(), save_path=save_path, save_name=save_name)

    # Record time to do forward passes and save images
    batch_time.update(time.time() - end)
    end = time.time()

    # Print model accuracy -- in the code below, val refers to both value and validation
    if i % 25 == 0:
      print('Validate: [{0}/{1}]\t'
            'Time {batch_time.val:.3f} ({batch_time.avg:.3f})\t'
            'Loss {loss.val:.4f} ({loss.avg:.4f})\t'.format(
             i, len(val_loader), batch_time=batch_time, loss=losses))

  print('Finished validation.')
  return losses.avg


def train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch):
    print('Starting training epoch {}'.format(epoch))
    model.train()

    # Prepare value counters and timers
    batch_time, data_time, losses = AverageMeter(), AverageMeter(), AverageMeter()

    end = time.time()
    for i, (input_gray, input_ab, target) in enumerate(train_loader):

        # Use GPU if available
        if use_gpu: input_gray, input_ab, target = input_gray.cuda(), input_ab.cuda(), target.cuda()

        # Record time to load data (above)
        data_time.update(time.time() - end)

        # Run forward pass
        output_ab = model(input_gray)
        loss = criterion(output_ab, input_ab)
        losses.update(loss.item(), input_gray.size(0))

        # Compute gradient and optimize
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()

        # Record time to do forward and backward passes
        batch_time.update(time.time() - end)
        end = time.time()

        # Print model accuracy -- in the code below, val refers to value, not validation
        if i % 25 == 0:
            print('Epoch: [{0}][{1}/{2}]\t'
                  'Time {batch_time.val:.3f} ({batch_time.avg:.3f})\t'
                  'Data {data_time.val:.3f} ({data_time.avg:.3f})\t'
                  'Loss {loss.val:.4f} ({loss.avg:.4f})\t'.format(
                epoch, i, len(train_loader), batch_time=batch_time,
                data_time=data_time, loss=losses))

    print('Finished training epoch {}'.format(epoch))

# Move model and loss function to GPU
if use_gpu:
  criterion = criterion.cuda()
  model = model.cuda()

# Make folders and set parameters
os.makedirs('outputs/color', exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs('outputs/gray', exist_ok=True)
os.makedirs('checkpoints', exist_ok=True)
save_images = True
best_losses = 1e10
epochs = 100

# Train model
for epoch in range(epochs):
  # Train for one epoch, then validate
  train(train_loader, model, criterion, optimizer, epoch)
  with torch.no_grad():
    losses = validate(val_loader, model, criterion, save_images, epoch)
  # Save checkpoint and replace old best model if current model is better
  if losses < best_losses:
    best_losses = losses
    torch.save(model.state_dict(), 'checkpoints/model-epoch-{}-losses-{:.3f}.pth'.format(epoch+1,losses))

# Show images
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
image_pairs = [('outputs/color/img-2-epoch-0.jpg', 'outputs/gray/img-2-epoch-0.jpg'),
               ('outputs/color/img-7-epoch-0.jpg', 'outputs/gray/img-7-epoch-0.jpg')]
for c, g in image_pairs:
  color = mpimg.imread(c)
  gray  = mpimg.imread(g)
  f, axarr = plt.subplots(1, 2)
  f.set_size_inches(15, 15)
  axarr[0].imshow(gray, cmap='gray')
  axarr[1].imshow(color)
  axarr[0].axis('off'), axarr[1].axis('off')
  plt.show()
```

So I do not know how to solve this or how to convert that variable to tensor !! and why it is working on my pc?  Thanks alot everyone!!

Comment: Check the versions of python3 on the two machines

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely because of mismatch of PyTorch versions between the server and your local computer. The notion of `Variable` being a concept separate from tensors has been deprecated with PyTorch 0.4, so I guess your local installation is newer than the server-side one.

You can check the PyTorch version by running

```
import torch
print(torch.__version__)
```

on both machines.